# Flask App is not showing data from Firestore Collection using Flask render_template()

Tags: python-3.x, list, flask, google-cloud-firestore, google-api-python-client

I have a small problem: I made a Flask App with a user interface, and in the user interface, the user can add, edit and delete a new item.

I am using Firestore as my data backend. For this function, I do not set the document id in Firestore. I use default and let Firestore set the document id.

I have no problem in adding a new record, and with the following code, I can display the records I created.

**Option 1**

My App Code

```
        donation = [doc.to_dict() for doc in donation_ref.stream()]        
        return render_template('donationlist.html', output=donation), 200
```

The data looks like this:

```
{'id': 'pixelone', 'firstname': 'Torbjorn', 'lastname': 'Zetterlund', 'email': 'test@test.com'}
```

My HTML code

```
                        <tbody>
                          {% if output %}
                            {% for ngo in output %}
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row"></th>
                              <td>{{ngo.id}}</td>
                              <td>{{ngo.email}}</td>
                              <td>{{ngo.firstname}}</td>
                              <td>{{ngo.lastname}}</td>  
                              <td>
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="/donationedit?id={{ ngo }}" title="Edit" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="/deletedonation?id={{ ngo }}" title="Delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Delete</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                          {% endif %}      
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
```

[image: Data is displaying]

The problem is that I need to set the document id for the edit and delete buttons. I do not have the document id in the output that holds my data for displaying. I made a small change to the code.

**Option 2**

In my App code, I made this change.

```
        donations = {}
        for doc in donation_ref.stream():
            donations[doc.id] = doc.to_dict()
        
        return render_template('donationlist.html', output=donations), 200
```

The data looks like this.

```
{'BA5ZXhW68g84ODSi4tYH': {'id': 'pixelone', 'firstname': 'Torbjorn', 'lastname': 'Zetterlund', 'email': 'test@test.com'}}
```

I now get the document id with the data I want to display, and I have one problem - I can get the document id and apply it to my edit and delete buttons. I have gotten stuck on how to get hold of the data to display. The template code looks the same.

```
                        <tbody>
                          {% if output %}
                            {% for ngo in output %}
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row"></th>
                              <td>{{ngo.id}}</td>
                              <td>{{ngo.email}}</td>
                              <td>{{ngo.firstname}}</td>
                              <td>{{ngo.lastname}}</td>  
                              <td>
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="/donationedit?id={{ ngo }}" title="Edit" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="/deletedonation?id={{ ngo }}" title="Delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Delete</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                          {% endif %}      
                        </tbody>
```

[image: Edit and Delete Button Works]

My issue is that I am not sure with the render_template how I can get to the data to display it in Option 2

```
  {% for ngo in output %}
```

When I use this code, it only takes the document id; the rest of the data is not available. There must be another way I have not been able to find the solution yet. I have done this with typescript in the past in an Angular app. So it can be done, just need to get to the data, so I hope someone out there can point me in the right direction.

The full Flask Code is available on GitHUb - https://github.com/greenpeace/TechLab-Pixel-Counter

Comment: I found the solution after trial and error on how to work list, string and object.                                  ```         donations = []     
        for doc in donation_ref.stream():
            don = doc.to_dict()
            don["docid"] = doc.id
            donations.append(don). ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, it was a code change

```
        donations = []     
        for doc in donation_ref.stream():
            don = doc.to_dict()
            don["docid"] = doc.id
            donations.append(don)
```